# Can evaluation metrics for test set be better than training set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am doing some Logistics Regression homework.

I just wonder if in any case, the evaluation metrics for the test set are a bit better than the training set (like my results below)? And if yes, what gap is allowed?

Below is my evaluation result for the test set and training set, given that both sets are extracted from the same dataset.

```
EVALUATION METRICS FOR Test Dataset:
Confusion Matrix:
                 Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
Actual Negative                  82                 20
Actual Positive                  10                 93

Accuracy = 0.8536585365853658
Precision = 0.8230088495575221
Recall = 0.9029126213592233
F1 score = 0.8380535530381049
```

```
EVALUATION METRICS FOR Training Dataset:
Confusion Matrix:
                 Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
Actual Negative                 279                 70
Actual Positive                  44                324

Accuracy = 0.8410041841004184
Precision = 0.8223350253807107
Recall = 0.8804347826086957
F1 score = 0.8315648343229267
```

Comment: Your test scores are slightly better than training scores, meaning that the test data is an accurate representation of the train data, which is a good thing. Getting a little above or below is normal, and it is also because the size of the test size is small, so the luck factor of getting a few more correct classifications significantly could have increased the accuracy

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut sorry, my fault for not noticing the NOTE. I will notice next time. Thank you so much

Comment: @GautamChettiar I got it, so luck also plays a role here. So, if I use this model for larger test datasets, and the test scores are still a little above or below the training scores, can I conclude that my model is a good model yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is not the case, but it is not impossible. If you randomly split your data into a test and a training set, the test data can fit better to your model than the training data in some cases. Imagine the extreme case below, where your data consists of values with different levels of noise added to it. If the test data points are the ones with less noise, they will fit better to the model. However, such a split into test and training data is very unlikely.

If the test score is just slightly above the training score, this is absolutely normal. If by chance, noise not captured by the model is slightly lower in the test data, the test samples will fit better to the model. Actually this a good sign, because it means that you are not over fitting. You may be able to increase overall performance by increasing the degrees of freedom in your model.

If the test score is much higher then the training score, you should check whether the split between test data and training has been done in a reasonable way.

[image: Plot of data and models]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 2*x + 3

x_test = np.random.rand(30)
x_training = np.random.rand(70)
y_test = f(x_test) + 1e-3 * np.random.randn(30)
y_training = f(x_training) + 0.2 * np.random.randn(70)
k, d = np.polyfit(x_training, y_training, 1)

x = np.linspace(0, 1)

plt.plot(x_training, y_training, 'o', label='training data')
plt.plot(x_test, y_test, 'o', label='test data')
plt.plot(x, k*x +d, 'k--', label='fitted model')
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'k:', label='real model')
plt.legend();
plt.show()
```

Comment: So I experiment by changing my random_state values when splitting my dataset multiple times and, printing out my validation, test, and training scores. 
Most of the time, my test accuracy is slightly higher than my others' accuracy, but some of them are indeed a little smaller than the training scores. So I wonder if I can conclude my model is good yet?

Comment: @Helena this sounds indeed surprising to me. I have no idea how to explain this behavior without looking into further details.

Comment: Thank you. Just one last thought. There is one detail that I thought would not be important to provide. So, I purposely sorted my dataset by label (for my other experiment), which means that data labelled 0 will be together, and 1 will be together. Could the sorting possibly affect my results?

Comment: @Helena yes definitely. If you sort samples before doing the split into test and training data, then the split won't be random. I don't fully understand what happens, but if samples with label 0 have less random noise than samples with label 1 and the sorting makes samples with label 0 go into the test set, then you end up exactly with the situation above. I think it would be a good idea to investigate further if this is a bug or a flawed model or training.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I know it was difficult to fully understand my situation without looking in my notebook or data, so I really appreciate your effort to help me. My situation was partly like that. After I changed that part in my code (which was eliminating the sorting), my test accuracy became randomly slightly higher or smaller than validation and training accuracy. But you're right, I can't conclude yet, I think I will investigate further into my training process and my model instead of preprocessing data. Thank you again 